# Blank box between menu items

Tags: html, menu

I am trying to make a horizontal menu

but these empty blocks are between my menu items (aprox 50px x 50px)

I used chrome inspect tool and these random blank anchors are there with nothing inside and ==$0 at the end

```css
.navbar{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.navbar a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    border: none;
    margin: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;    
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background: #54d5f2;
    color: black;

}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>I Want Flowers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="navbar">
   <a href="./homepage.html">Home Page<a/>
   <a href="./products.html">Products<a/>
   <a href="./storelocations.html">Store Locations</a>
   <a href="./contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First two anchor tags are not closed properly

Answer (score 1):

Its because you close your `<a>` like this: `<a/>` instead of `</a>` here:

```
<a href="./homepage.html">Home Page<a/>
<a href="./products.html">Products<a/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you make mistake while closing the anchor tags

```
<a href="./homepage.html">Home Page<a/>
```

to

```
<a href="./homepage.html">Home Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace you HTML by this HTML

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="./homepage.html">Home Page</a>
  <a href="./products.html">Products</a>
  <a href="./storelocations.html">Store Locations</a>
  <a href="./contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That was the after effects of not closing the anchor tag as it should have been.
Just change `<a/>` to `</a>` and you're good to go.. :)

```css
.navbar{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.navbar a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 25px;
    border: none;
    margin: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;    
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background: #54d5f2;
    color: black;

}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>I Want Flowers</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="navbar">
   <a href="./homepage.html">Home Page</a>
   <a href="./products.html">Products</a>
   <a href="./storelocations.html">Store Locations</a>
   <a href="./contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```